# How to deploy a private google cloudsql instance assigning exiting vpc (network_interface) using terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-sql, terraform-provider-gcp, google-vpc

I have a custom vpc - configured with vpc peering and all. Now I want to deploy a cloudsql instance using terraform under that vpc with only private ip. Can anyone have any suggestions regarding that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Terraform well, but in the docs for terraform:

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/sql_database_instance.html

Do a search on "VPC" and it has this snippet:

```
  provider = google-beta

  name = "private-network"
}

resource "google_compute_global_address" "private_ip_address" {
  provider = google-beta

  name          = "private-ip-address"
  purpose       = "VPC_PEERING"
  address_type  = "INTERNAL"
  prefix_length = 16
  network       = google_compute_network.private_network.self_link
}

resource "google_service_networking_connection" "private_vpc_connection" {
  provider = google-beta

  network                 = google_compute_network.private_network.self_link
  service                 = "servicenetworking.googleapis.com"
  reserved_peering_ranges = [google_compute_global_address.private_ip_address.name]
}
```

I believe that's the config bits you need?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. With your format, it will create a new vpc with peering connection and private ip, along with cloudsql instance. But I have the vpc already configured and want to attach with my cloudsql with only private ip. here am not found any proper documentation. don't want to create a new vpc just to attach the existing one thru terraform.